# How use Lambda handleHeavyContent() in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, line-api

Sample code: https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-java/blob/master/sample-spring-boot-kitchensink/src/main/java/com/example/bot/spring/KitchenSinkController.java

I try convert to Kotlin.

But responseBody is Type mismatch.

```
    handleHeavyContent(
        event.replyToken,
        event.message.id
        ) {responseBody ->
    }
```

Required:
Consumer

Found: (???) -> Unit

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem so after some searches finally I came up with some ways to define a lambda in a function.
In your case I would do something like this

```
fun handleHeavyContent(
    event.replyToken,
    event.message.id,
    response : (ResponseBody) -> Unit){
     //do your code and get the response body and pass it to the variable
     // get the body from a function or object and then use it like this
     val body : ResponseBody //initialize it here
     response(body)
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Sorry, my description is not good enough, I tried to post this question again and close this page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398575/consumer-cant-find-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Example fun with Unit and lamba use:

```
fun x(
    val a: Int,
    val b: (param: Int) -> Unit
) {
    // any code
    b.invoke(a)
}


x(1) { param ->
   println(param) // -> gives 1
}
```

Your function, after refactoring, must be missing parameter for lamba

Comment: Sorry, my description is not good enough, I tried to post this question again and close this page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398575/consumer-cant-find-in-kotlin